# Do something after http load failed

Tags: swift

In my app I have a text field where a user can enter a url. It does not go to a http website. I want it so that when It tries to load an http site, the user will be shown an error message.

How would I do this?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "\(enter url.text!)")   
let request = NSRequest(url: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

I did add this:

```
optional func webView(_ webView: UIWebView,
 didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?)
```

It did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, you should show some code, and some of your attempts to solve the problem

Comment: What error message?  How do you want it shown?

Comment: For now, I want it to print "http website!!"

Comment: I want it do detect if a website is http or https. If it is http, I want it do do something, for example print "http website".

Comment: So you want to parse the url and see whether it starts with http:// ?

Comment: Yep. The place where the user can enter the url starts with a https://.

Comment: I basically want to check if a website uses http or https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you didn't set delegate method, that's why it didn't call that function. So follow these steps :-

**Step 1**

You need to add webView Delegate in viewDidLoad() :-

```
  override func viewDidLoad() { 
      self.webView.delegate = self
      //Other codes...
  }
```

**Step 2**

```
  func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
       if error != nil {
               //calls when show up error
          }
  }
```